# Approach for calculating Alcubierre energy function?

Tags: general-relativity, faster-than-light, warp-drives

**NOTE:** I know that the Alcubierre drive is on shaky ground and I'm not asking about its practicality or physical feasibility. I'm also not looking for answers like, "It's sci-fi so you can just make it up." Thank you.

---

I'm working on the FTL mechanics for a sci-fi project, and in the search for a somewhat mathematically rigorous model for a warp drive, I've been looking for an equation for the Alcubierre drive's fuel requirement. I've come across this formula:
$$
-\frac{c^4}{8\pi G}\frac{v_s^2(y^2+z^2)}{4g^2r_s^2}\Big(\frac{df}{dr_s}\Big)^2
$$
This is the energy density equation for a given position in the Alcubierre spacetime. The parameter $r_s$ represents the position in the warp bubble, and the function $f(r_s)$ is the shaping function for the bubble, including parameters for the bubble's radius and thickness. The parameter $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor, which I believe to be $-c^2$, and $v_s$ is the velocity function of the drive.

**What I'm after** is a function that gives me the *total* energy required per second for the drive to function, given only the warp bubble's thickness, its radius, and the drive's velocity. **What I believe I have to do next** is to perform an integration over the x, y, and z dimensions, but I'm pretty unsure. I'd like to know if this is the correct approach, and if not, what the correct approach would be.

Comment: No *energy per second* is required. Once you've built the drive it keeps going (at FTL speeds) without needing any energy input.

Comment: @JohnRennie Why is that?

Comment: @JohnRennie Nevermind, I think I see why. Either way, would integrating over x, y, and z bring me from "energy per unit area" to "total energy" like I thought?